# existing filesystem error on adding old btrfs storage volume into new ubuntu lxd install

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lxc

```
lxc storage create default btrfs source=/dev/sdc
error: Failed to create the BTRFS pool: /dev/sdc appears to contain an existing filesystem (btrfs).
ERROR: use the -f option to force overwrite of /dev/sdc
btrfs-progs v4.9.1
See http://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org for more information.
```

i am sketch of giving the -f options as i don't want to lose my existing containers and fear it will clobber the disk.

Comment: Since I do not know the original command you ran to get that output, have you tried the `mount /dev/sdc /mnt` command? In most modern linux OS, the mount command is smart enough to interpret the type of filesystem on the disk, and mount it, too.

Comment: the command is "lxc storage create default btrfs source=/dev/sdc" the fs type is btrfs, but lxd is throwing that error.

Answer (score 0):

i gave up on simply adding the existing storage volume to a storage pool. i got up quickly with access to the previous install by restoring the lxd config.

```
service lxd stop
mkdir /mnt/old
mount /dev/OLDDRIVE /mnt/old
mv /var/lib/lxd /var/lib/lxd.old
cp -R /mnt/old/var/lib/lxd /var/lib/
service lxd start
lxc list
```

i still have the rest of the install to test...